# Did the Romans have a Latin word for 1000 years?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

Did the Romans have a specific word to imply 1000 years? *Millennium* is Latin, of course, but it's later Latin and I'm trying to find something more classical. There are more general words for periods of time, but I haven't found anything that is specifically 1000 years.

For some added context, if I wanted to say we're in the third millennium, *third millennium* is succinct in English but could be less succinct in Latin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They did not have one single word like we do/Neo-Latin did with *millennium*. When Cicero talks about "thousands of years", he simply says [*multa annorum milia*](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/474/48/51/2189-2192,2212-2216@1#51).

One workaround later authors used is the adjective *miliarius*. Tertullian ([*De Anima 31*](https://tertullian.org/latin/de_anima.htm)) has *aevum miliarium* to mean "a period of 1000 years." It's two words, but it does seem to be a singular unit of sorts. The only issue is that I don't see it in anything earlier than Tertullian. While it was typically used substantively in the neuter to mean "milestone marker" Augustine ([*Civ. Dei* 20.7](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/augustine/civ20.shtml)) uses *miliarium annorum*. It's quite a bit later than "Classical Rome," but it's probably the closest you'll get to "millennium."

An off-the-wall suggestion could be *decem saecula*, using the narrower meaning of *saeculum* as a period of one hundred years (and I suppose adding the *decem* to it would suggest that particular meaning).

Comment: Thanks! Tertullian is close enough to classical for my comfort.